# Prevent hubspot form submission - jQuery validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, hubspot

I would like to prevent submission if form is not valid and to print some error message if possible, here's what I have so far:

btw "link to the current page" is defined in php

```
hbspt.forms.create({
    css: '',
    portalId: 'hs-portal-id-goes-here',
    formId: 'hs-form-id-goes-here',  
    onFormReady: function(){
        jQuery('#hsForm_hs-form-id-goes-here').validate({
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {},
            rules: {
                firstname: { required: true },
                lastname: { required: true },
                email: { required: true },
                message: { required: true }
            },
            submitHandler: function(form, e) { 
                e.preventDefault();
                window.open('link to the current page', '_self');
                form.submit();
                jQuery(newForm)
                var newForm = jQuery('#hsForm_hs-form-id-goes-here');
                window.setTimeout(function() {
                    newForm.html('<h3>Thank you for submitting the form</h3>');
                }, 1000);
            }
       });
    }
});
```

Comment: This just sounds like ordinary client validation to me.  Are you getting some error message that we can look at?

Comment: actually no, if  form isn't valid hubspot does not receiving the data, but "Thank you for submitting the form" message is being displayed anyway

Comment: Then you need to write some client-side validation code.

Comment: agreed, I was just wondering if it's necessary to include this too

http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/additional-methods.min.js

Answer (score 2):

Do you want client-side or server-side validation?

If answer is client-side, you should do it with javascript, check inputs and write validation messages.

If it is server-side, you should consider using ajax, serialize your form, send it to server, and react depending on answer (was data successfully validated, or not)

Comment: In addition, make both (frontend-backend) validations is still better.

Comment: In addition, the form is embedded from hubspot on external page (embedded with js), what I'm actually trying to do is to open the embedded form in modal - so I guess "back-end" or better to say server-side validation is out of the option, I just need "preventDefault()" in case form isn't valid, that's all

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't read your question at all. I only improved this answer with a short comment. Anyway seems you know what to do so I don't understand where is the problem exactly. @Darko

Comment: @kmsdev No offense mate, actually the issue was with the validation working only once - the 1st time modal is being opened , so I wrapped up entire "hbspt.forms.create" into another function, and I call it each time the modal window is opened, that's it, thx for the comment btw :)